# Get the latest record by date with the same object name

Tags: mysql

How can I get courseName = 'Music' with the latest date?

```
courseName      |   dateOfEnrollment
----------------|-----------------------
Music           |   2016-07-24
Art             |   2016-07-01
Art             |   2016-07-23  
Music           |   2016-07-25
```

As I tried with the statement below

```
SELECT courseName, dateOfEnrollment FROM MyDatabase.dbo.courseEnrollment WHERE courseName = 'Music' AND GETDATE() >= MAX(dateOfEnrollment)
```

it returns error:

```
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
```

My ultimate goal is to put that statement in an IF statement, if it is not null, then I will insert new data into the table.

**Update (My answer):**

This is working for me:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 courseName, dateOfEnrollment FROM courseEnrollment WHERE courseName = 'Music' ORDER BY dateOfEnrollment DESC)
    *Insert data into the table*

ELSE
    *No need to insert*
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    courseName,
    dateOfEnrollment
FROM
    MyDatabase.dbo.courseEnrollment
WHERE
    courseName = 'Music'
ORDER BY
    dateOfEnrollment
LIMIT 1
```

That's how your query should look like, but assuming your main goal - you only need to check is there any 'Music' row, you should not be interested in `dateOfEnrollment` column at all. Am i right or missed something?

So your final query (to insert a row depending on a condition) will be:

```
INSERT INTO courseEnrollment
SELECT 'Music', CURDATE() FROM courseEnrollment
WHERE courseName = 'Music';
```

Comment: If two or more than two record contains latest same date then what happen?

Comment: Found two problems there. 1) `ORDER BY dateOfEnrollment` means `ascending order of date (but expected is descending order)` 2) if there are more than one entries under `Music` having the latest date then there will be always 1 in the output.

Comment: Hi @Damiano, thanks for your reply. May I know how can I put the whole query into an IF statement? Let say if there is no result return, then table will not be updated. else update the table.

Comment: Edited, check it and let me know

Comment: @Damiano, thanks for your effort and it gave me some idea, but I found an answer that is close to what I want. Anyway, a vote up for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
CE.*
FROM courseEnrollment CE
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        courseName,
        MAX(dateOfEnrollment) max_enrollment_date
    FROM courseEnrollment
    WHERE courseName ='Music'
) t
ON CE.courseName = t.courseName AND CE.dateOfEnrollment = t.max_enrollment_date;
```

**Note:** The output of this query might contain more than one entries if multiple entries under `Music` course have the latest date.

---

**TEST:**

```
CREATE TABLE courseEnrollment (
    courseName VARCHAR (100),
    dateOfEnrollment date
);

INSERT INTO courseEnrollment (
    courseName,
    dateOfEnrollment
)
VALUES
    ('Music', '2016-07-24'),
    ('Art', '2016-07-01'),
    ('Art', '2016-07-23'),
    ('Music', '2016-07-25');
```

Running the above query on these given data you will get an output like below:

**Output:**

```
courseName        dateOfEnrollment
Music               2016-07-25
```

**EDIT:**

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a45c/1/0)</kbd>